# What are the limitations for zip file extraction in Azure Search?

Tags: azure

My indexer shows an error for two zip files (size of 800MB) saying that the zip file has "the size of ... bytes, which exceeds the maximum size for document extraction for your curent service tier." Azure Search is already set on a Standard tier. Is the solution to go to a higher tier? Cause from the documentation I gather that the limit is the same across all Standard tiers? If there is a limit to the size of zip files to be extracted, then what is it? And would the solution for bigger files then be to unzip it before Azure Search?

Answer (score 0):

Maximum running times exist to provide balance and stability to the service as a whole, but larger data sets might need more indexing time than the maximum allows. If an indexing job cannot complete within the maximum time allowed, try running it on a schedule. Here is [indexer limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#indexer-limits) you could refer to.

**Note**: A service is provisioned at a specific tier. Jumping tiers to gain capacity involves provisioning a new service (**there is no in-place upgrade**). For more information, see [Choose a SKU or tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-sku-tier). To learn more about adjusting capacity within a service you've already provisioned, see [Scale resource levels for query and indexing workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-capacity-planning).